# First click not rendering correct data [second click works]?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo

I have a menu here, made with a horizontal flatlist:

[image]

Code for menu:

```
<View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0 }}>
    <FlatList
      horizontal
      data={categories}
      extraData={
      selectedCategory // for single item
    }
      style={styles.flatList}
      renderItem={({ item: rowData }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => recalculateCategory(rowData)} 
          style={rowData === selectedCategory ? styles.selected : styles.unselected}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#FFFFFF', padding: 6 }}>
            { rowData }
          </Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
    />
  </View>
```

Code for recalculateCategory:

```
const recalculateCategory = (rowData) => {
  setSelectedCategory(rowData);
  getCollection();
};
```

code for getCollection:

```
const getCollection = async() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const index = 1;
    const getThoughtsOneCategory = Firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getThoughtsOneCategory');
    await getThoughtsOneCategory({
      index,
      category: selectedCategory,
    }).then((result) => {
      setThoughts(result.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };
```

How it works is: if you want to see options posts, you click options, and it renders the data accordingly.

I am running into an issue.

1. We are on "STOCKS"

[image: ADDED]

2. Click on "OPTIONS" [Notice the data is the same as "STOCKS"]

[image]

3. Click on "OPTIONS" again, and we get the correct data

[image]

How can I fix this requirement to double click on a menu category? Thanks

Comment: You don't seem to have included enough code to diagnose this. Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: Specifically`` recalculateCategory(rowData), it would be good to see what that does

Comment: @StarshipladDev hey! I added a bit more code

Comment: @jnpdx hey! I added more code. The fetching happens in the cloud function, I can add that too if necessary, but this seems like an issue on the frontend to me because that works fine according to logs

Comment: What happens if you click again to a new tab? do you need to click twice again to see the proper data or the issue happens just on the first time?

Comment: @programandoconro every time I click on a new tab, I have to click twice to get the updated data.

Comment: @kalculated I love what this idea seems to be btw!

Comment: @StarshipladDev thank you!! if you have an iPhone its traderank on the App Store. unfortunately if I don't solve this issue our users won't have a new feature tomorrow :(

Comment: `setSelectedCategory` is asynchronous and will not have finished by the time you call `getCollection`. You should either use a `useEffect` to run `getCollection` or send the category as a parameter to `getCollection`. Do you know how to do either of those?

Comment: @jnpdx new to functional components! most of the rest of the app is class components. it would be helpful if you can provide an example of using useEffect for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `getCollection` directly, you could use `useEffect` to call it whenever the category changes.

Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCollection();
},[selectedCategory])
```

And then your `recalculateCategory` would just look like:

```
const recalculateCategory = (rowData) => {
  setSelectedCategory(rowData);
};
```

`useEffect` runs whenever the parameters in the second argument change. You may need to adjust them to fit your use case, but `selectedCategory` would definitely be in there.